# Next.js VS Code proxy

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, proxy, yarnpkg

When I use the proxy, I create a Next.js project, and then I close the proxy. After entering the project, neither Yarn nor NPM can be used, and after troubleshooting, it is found that there is such an error in the project package.json Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8902. I checked the proxy settings for Yarn and NPM and neither is set. Now I can't add packages to the project without turning on the host agent.